# How to save my model using Parse cloud js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I had a read of the meme example but it doesn't seem to update, just create new objects! What I want is to

```
a. find some given db table
b. update some fields in the db table
c. save the db table back to the database
```

Given this code, what is the missing piece so that I can actually update an object?

```
query.find( 
    function(results){
        if (results.length > 0){
           return results[0];
        } else {
            //no object found, so i want to make an object... do i do that here?
            return null;
        }
    },
    function(error){
        response.error("ServerDown");
        console.error("ServerDown - getModuleIfAny URGENT. Failed to retrieve from the ModuleResults table" +  +error.code+ " " +error.message);
    }
).then(
    function(obj){
        var module;
        if (obj != null){
            console.log("old");
            module = obj;
            module.moduleId = 10; //let's just say this is where i update the field
            //is this how i'd update some column in the database?
        } else {
            console.log("new");
            var theModuleClass = Parse.Object.extend("ModuleResults");
            module= new theModuleClass();
        }

        module.save().then(
            function(){
                response.success("YAY");
            },
            function(error) {
                response.error('Failed saving: '+error.code);
            } 
        );
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("sod");
    }
);
```

I thought the above code would work - but it does not. When it finds an object, it instead refuses to save, stupidly telling me that my object has no "save" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would double check the version of the javascript sdk you're using in your cloud code. Make sure it's up to date e.g. 1.2.8. The version is set in the config/global.json file under your cloud code directory.

Assuming you're up to date I would try modifying your code by chaining the promises using multiple then's like so:

```
query.find().then(function(results){
                      if (results.length > 0){
                          return results[0];
                      } else {
                          //no object found, so i want to make an object... do i do that here?
                          return null;
                      }
                  },
                  function(error){
                      response.error("ServerDown");
                      console.error("ServerDown - getModuleIfAny URGENT. Failed to retrieve from            the ModuleResults table" +  +error.code+ " " +error.message);
             }).then(function(obj){
    var module;
    if (obj != null){
        console.log("old");
        module = obj;
        module.moduleId = 10; //let's just say this is where i update the field
        //is this how i'd update some column in the database?
    } else {
        console.log("new");
        var theModuleClass = Parse.Object.extend("ModuleResults");
        module= new theModuleClass();
    }

    module.save();
}).then(function(result) {
          // the object was saved.
        }, 
        function(error) {
           // there was some error.
        });
```

I *think* this should work. Fingers crossed. Cheers!

Comment: how did you get the version for the latest parse cloud sdk?